# How do I use a constant LETTER in sympy?

Tags: python, sympy

I want to print the derivative of `e**4*x`. I want Python to give me `4*e**4x`. Instead, it's giving me 4 times THE VALUE OF E. HOw can I get sympy to display e as the letter constant.

Thanks

Comment: Well, because d/dx [(e^4)x] = 4e. I'm not sure how to get the display you want, but the answer value you want can be gotten be adding parens: `e**(4*x)`.

Comment: It's: d/dx [e^(4x)]. What I want is sympy to actually return the e, not it's value but the actual letter.

Comment: I understand that, I'm just telling you part of the problem. I don't know the actual solution you're looking for; I've never worked with sympy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that by default in SymPy the base of the natural logarithm is `E` (capital `E`). That is, `exp(x)` is the same as `E**x`.

Comment: Maybe it is clearer to write sympy.E=sympy.exp(1)

Answer (score 2):

You should be using `exp` to represent exponents as opposed to the letter `e`.

Example, it should be like this:

```
from sympy import *
x = symbols('x')

print diff(exp(4*x))
```

This outputs:

```
4*exp(4*x)
```

As desired.

Regarding the problem with your code - Without much more else to go on - it seems like you've set `e` to be a variable somewhere.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It worked like a charm.

No, it was seeing e correctly, the problem was that it was replacing e with the euler number instead of simply using the symbol. It was deriving ok, but I couldn't check my answers because it would always multiply the coefficient of e and the actual value of e.

Answer (score 1):

You have perhaps assigned E to the letter e (or the environment you are working in did that). To work around that here are a few ways to define the symbols you need:

```
>>> var('e x') # or from sympy.abc import x, e or x, e = symbols('x e')
(e, x)
>>> diff(e**(4*x), x)
4*e**(4*x)*log(e)
```